# Expanding clickable area of anchor element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my nav bar, there is one button which is floated to the right with a padding of 200px.

However, the clickabale area isn't expanded. What is a proper way to solve this issue?

[image: Page Design]

```css
body {
  font-family: impact;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
}
footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 250px;
}
.menu-header a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-header a:hover {
  background: #000;
}
.menu-header {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul.menu-header li a {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul.menu-header li:nth-of-type(6) {
  float: right;
  /*last button on the right-hand side*/
}
li:nth-of-type(6) {
  padding-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu-header">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">
        <img width="13px" height="13px" src="images/fridge.png">What's Left?</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="fridge.html">Mein Kühlschrank</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="buylist.html">Einkaufsliste</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="recipe.html">Rezepte vorschlagen</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="login.html">Menü</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="content">
  Ich bin der Inhalt</br>
  und ich meine es verdammt ernst
</div>
<footer>
  ich bin der Fuss
</footer>
```

If I change the last line of code to exactly the same but 4th child it doesn't respond to the padding.

The same if I change to `li a:nth-of-type(6)` or `li:nth-of-type(6) a`.

Magically, if I change the padding from the first child it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this on the `li`:

```
li:nth-of-type(6) {
    padding-right: 200px;
}
```

Instead, apply that rule to the `a`:

```
li:nth-of-type(6) a {
    padding-right: 200px !important; /* you may need to override other rules */
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9o15br24/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, works exactly as i supposed it to. So is it right, that the first statement is what the code is looking for and the second what it changes when it is true?

Comment: In your original code, you were expanding the parent (`li`) with the padding rule, but nothing was expanding the child (`a`). In my answer, we are targeting the `a` that is a descendant of the 6th `li`. By applying the padding to the child, both the child and the parent are expanded.